# angular http post adds extra params to the request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I have the following in a directive:

```
scope.progressCourse = ->
  req_data =
    course_id: scope.course.id
    success: true

  $http.post(
    "<%= Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.progress_course_path %>",
    req_data
  ).then (succesful_resp) ->
    scope.course = succesful_resp.data.data
    scope.init_from_course_object()
  , (error_resp) ->
    show_error(error_resp)
```

And, server side, I'd expect to receive the course_id and success params. However, I receive something extra:

```
  Parameters: {"course_id"=>1, "success"=>true, "training"=>{"course_id"=>1, "success"=>true}}
```

The request is addressed to a controller called TrainingController. I'm running Rails 3.2.13, with angular 1.2.10. Could someone explain why the extra hash appears `{"training"=>{"course_id"=>1, "success"=>true}}`

UPDATE:
If I add this:

```
  $httpProvider.defaults.transformRequest = (data) ->
    if data?
      return $.param(data)
    return data
```

and I change the post to:

```
  $http(
    method: "POST"
    url: "<%= Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.progress_course_path %>",
    data: req_data,
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'}
  ).then (succesful_resp) ->
```

Then I only get the 2 params I need. Can someone explain why this behaviour?

Comment: have you verified, whether the extra hash is generated within your js-code (for example by renaming the fields in the `req_data` block and see what happens)? do you have a `<form>` in your DOM specifying the `training[course_id]` and `training[success]` fields (which would be the usual parameter naming convention in a rails RESTful form)?

Comment: can you post a sample app on github which reproduces this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails has a lot of inbuilt functionality to make dealing with external APIs easier. In this case it has a **params_wrapper** that will manipulate parameters passed in in a request, nesting them in the hash that it assumes you want.

For example, if you are submitting `{name: 'foo', age: 12}` to a UsersController, it will assume that they should be wrapped in a nested `user` key and will do this for you transparently.

Documentation for this wrapper is here:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/classes/ActionController/ParamsWrapper.html

And the code is here:

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.2.13/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb

If you don't want this functionality, you can disable it by commenting out the `wrap_parameters format: [:json]` line in `/config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb`.